# Web scrape table to excel using selenium, python

Tags: python-3.x, excel, selenium, csv, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to put this information on an excel file, but can't seem to figure out how to use `import csv` for it. I looked at other posts as reference but I can't seem to apply it for what I'm doing. I'm sort of new to selenium. Thank you.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import csv

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://web3.ncaa.org/hsportal/exec/hsAction")

state_drop = driver.find_element_by_id("state")
state = Select(state_drop)
state.select_by_visible_text("New Jersey")

driver.find_element_by_id("city").send_keys("Galloway")
driver.find_element_by_id("name").send_keys("Absegami High School")
driver.find_element_by_class_name("forms_input_button").send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
driver.find_element_by_id("hsSelectRadio_1").click()

#scraping the caption of the tables
all_sub_head = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("tableSubHeaderForWsrDetail") 

#scraping all the headers of the tables
all_headers = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("tableHeaderForWsrDetail")

#filtering the desired headers
required_headers = all_headers[5:]

#scraoing all the table data
all_contents = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("tdTinyFontForWsrDetail")

#filtering the desired tabla data
required_contents = all_contents[45:]
```

Answer (score 0):

`all_contents` is a list of objects.

**List comprehension** is a quick and common way to gather property values from objects into another list.

Add these lines to the bottom of your script

```
lstdata = [e.text for e in required_contents]

with open('out.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(lstdata)
```

Note that you have newlines in your data, so they will appear in the csv file (school address column)